# Clonezilla hangs after boot

Tags: debian, dual-boot, pxe, clonezilla

I have installed clonezilla live on pxe server.
My pxe server works fine and I have installed clonezilla image in it to boot from remote location.

My clonezilla image is booting successfully but it's hang after keyboard selection sometimes and sometimes gives error: **" modprobe: module vesafb not found in modules.dep"**

I have followed below links for this installation:

1. For PXE Server Installation, https://wiki.debian.org/PXEBootInstall
2. For Clonezilla Installation, http://clonezilla.org/livepxe.php

I have tried with different versions of clonezilla like 1.2.0-25, 2.4.2-10, 2.4.2-10-2, 2.4.2-10-i586, 2.4.2-17, 20150608-vivid-amd64, etc. but didn't get succeed to boot clonezilla after keyboard mapping.

My /srv/tftp/ contents is as below:

```
    root@debian-kavin:/srv/tftp# tree -L 3
    .
    ├── ]
    ├── debian-installer
    │   └── amd64
    │       ├── bootnetx64.efi
    │       ├── boot-screens
    │       ├── grub
    │       ├── initrd.gz
    │       ├── linux
    │       ├── pxelinux.0
    │       └── pxelinux.cfg
    ├── filesystem.squashfs
    ├── initrd.img
    ├── ldlinux.c32 -> debian-installer/amd64/boot-screens/ldlinux.c32
    ├── pxelinux.0 -> debian-installer/amd64/pxelinux.0
    ├── pxelinux.cfg -> debian-installer/amd64/pxelinux.cfg
    ├── version.info
    └── vmlinuz
```